How to extract and call Runtimes Calls
Could you explain me how Runtimes calls (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpolkadot-rpc-tn.dwellir.com#/runtime) are extracted and called from v14 Metadata ?
I went throw the Polkadot JS code (the API repo) and if I understand correctly, these runtimes calls are defined inside the v15 metadata classe :
MetadataV15: {
    lookup: 'PortableRegistry',
    pallets: 'Vec<PalletMetadataV15>',
    extrinsic: 'ExtrinsicMetadataV15',
    type: 'SiLookupTypeId',
    apis: 'Vec<RuntimeApiMetadataV15>',
    outerEnums: 'OuterEnums15',
    custom: 'CustomMetadata15'
  }

Currently only v14 is available from Polkadot node, and it seems that v14 instance is mapped to "MetadataLatest" which is v15.
Thanks a lot for your help

The default metadata fallbacks to V14.
However, there is a new call metadata.metadataVersions: Vec<u32>.
You can invoke this first to retrieve the supported versions.
If 15 is in the list.
Then, you can call metadata.metadataAtVersion(15): Option<OpaqueMetadata> to obtain the V15 metadata.

Thanks a lot for your answer.
I am currently working on the .NET stack so we have to redevelop everything (I cannot call PolkadotJs Api). Currently we are able to call all the JSON-RPC / Constants / Storage / Extrinsics / Events / Errors, but not the Runtimes Calls.
How can I build the "api.call.xxxx" methods ?
Thanks :)

Ok, it seems related to ApisVec in RuntimeVersion, but I don't know how to convert this

Please don't derail the current topic. Feel free to pose another question on this site. (How to xxx with .net?..)
